# How to convert Relative Path into absolute path in c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

I have stored Database in the main folder of my project, I am using Relative Path while i use that database. Now i need to convert this realtive path into absolute path at runtime
I used tha following code but it doesnt work

```
string Path1 = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MakeMyBill.sdf";
string fullpath=Path.GetFullPath(Path1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
String absolutePath = Server.MapPath(myRelativePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like HostingEnvironment

```
string logDirectory = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~") + "\\" + "App_Data\\MakeMyBill.sdf";
```

or

```
string logDirectory =Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/MakeMyBill.sdf")
```

or on any folder

```
     string filePath = @"D:\file\";
        string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
        filePath = directoryName + @"\file.xml";
```